# How to create a Micro Frontend bundle with Webpack that shares libraries with the container application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, architecture, microservices, micro-frontend

I have a task.

To have Micro Frontends with single-spa framework.

1. portal/main application (which load all other js code by url)
2. Micro Frontend 1 (react based)
3. Micro Frontend 2 (react based)

So my problem just one: I don't want to duplicate vendor libraries like react, react-dom (any others). And I want to make them shared among other Micro Frontends (which is bundled with webpack)

I know what is the bad practice to have some global stuff (it's violate the whole idea of bundeling with webpack). But how to solve the problem of duplication of vendor libraries?

I found one solution just load decencies with SystemJs like separated  tags in html, but I just wonder maybe there is another solutuion for that.

Thank you.

SystemJs approach to load dependencies by demand but from CDN, I just want do the same but load all dependencies from "shared" webpack bundle with react and other stuff.

```
window.SystemJS = window.System

function insertNewImportMap(newMapJSON) {
  const newScript = document.createElement('script')
  newScript.type = 'systemjs-importmap'
  newScript.text = JSON.stringify(newMapJSON)
  const allMaps = document.querySelectorAll('script[type="systemjs-importmap"]')

  allMaps[allMaps.length - 1].insertAdjacentElement(
    'afterEnd',
    newScript
  )
}

const devDependencies = {
  imports: {
    react: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.development.js',
    'react-dom': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.development.js',
    'react-dom/server': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom-server.browser.development.js',
    'single-spa': 'https://unpkg.com/single-spa@4.3.2/lib/umd/single-spa.min.js',
    lodash: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js',
    rxjs: 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.js',
  }
}

const prodDependencies = {
  imports: {
    react: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js',
    'react-dom': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js',
    'react-dom/server': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js',
    'single-spa': 'https://unpkg.com/single-spa@4.3.2/lib/umd/single-spa.min.js',
    lodash: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js',
    rxjs: 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js',
  }
}

const devMode = true // you will need to figure out a way to use a set of production dependencies instead
if (devMode) {
  insertNewImportMap(devDependencies)
} else {
  insertNewImportMap(prodDependencies)
}
```

Comment: Realized you want to develop a Micro Frontend. Updated your title and my answer to focus more on this concrete topic. Hope, it helps now.

Answer (score 6):

Update:

Just realized, that your question is directed at [Micro Frontends](https://micro-frontends.org/) (not only micro services) and therefore is not about sharing libraries with Webpack in general. Added Micro Frontend to your tags/title and updated the answer to be more focused on this topic.

---

> So my problem just one: I don't want to duplicate vendor libraries like react, react-dom (any others). And I want to make them shared among other [Micro Frontends] (which is bundled with webpack)

What you can do is exclude dependencies from the output bundle of your Micro Frontends by adding a [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) property to the config.

webpack config of your Micro Frontends:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  externals = {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  }
}
```

Above config would exclude `react` and `react-dom` and expect them in the global variables `React` and `ReactDOM`. You can then share those dependencies by including the libraries in a script inside `index.html` of your root applicationn aka stitching layer:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="<your-host>/react.prod-16.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<your-host>/react-dom.prod-16.9.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you have other common components to share, you can also integrate the library scripts in a [component library](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html#SharedComponentLibraries).

The reason for the include as script is: We do not want that our container has to [require/import the Micro Frontends at build time](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html#Build-timeIntegration) in order to avoid a coupling of build/release/version management between all apps. Instead one purpose of Micro Frontends is to achieve fully [independent deployment](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html#IndependentDeployment) of the parts, which include continuous delivery steps from build, test to release.

> I know what is the bad practice to have some global stuff (it's violate the whole idea of bundeling with webpack).

Of course, you create some form of coupling between the apps. But if you have a mature, stable and common library shared by all parts, it is a reasonable decision.

Hope, it helps (now)!

Comment: hello, thank you for you reply! I will try it and back to you to put more comment which might help others. Cheers.

Comment: No problem, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this today is using Webpack's new Module Federation technology released in v5. This approach does not use SystemJS but rather the internals of Webpack. We tried several different micro frontend approaches, but this one outshines them all & is currently running successfully for us in production. There are definitely some challenges to setting it up but it was worth the developer productivity gains.

Here is the info site produced by the creator Zack Jackson which should provide all the resources you need: https://module-federation.github.io/

Here is the link to webpack docs which deal more with technicalities rather than how to practically set up a full micro frontend architecture: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/

Comment: it seems like most of the apps that they done in react . I'm actually looking my existing angular app by splitting into more apps even login page should consider as a different app . With angular , we need to use YARN instead of NPM . So i wanted to do with webpack only approach. It would be really nice if you can suggest me some samples

Comment: @AhammadaliPK we use yarn as well. There shouldn't be any difference if you use yarn or npm :) Here are some angular examples though: https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples

Comment: yup no difference , but i'm only allowed to use NPM , too hard to get YARN installed at server