# How to get external dependencies from a parent webpack project

Tags: webpack

I'm working with a micro-frontend style architecture. Currently each individual micro UI has its own copy of all of its dependencies. Because all the sizes are so small to begin with, my team hasn't been worried about the bundle cost of duplicate dependencies yet (heavily optimized tree shaking helps). But as we scale up, it's something that I feel we may need to address.

I've been researching how to use externals to share libraries with a webpack bundle. The thing is, all the documentation I have seen seems to involve the dependency coming from something like a CDN via a  tag. I'm not sure how well that'll work on our corporate network, I've heard some chatter about how we are avoiding CDNs.

Anyway, I'm wondering if there is a way for webpack to get external dependencies from a parent webpack app. So the first webpack app loads the dependencies, and then the micro frontends (which are loaded afterwards) get their dependencies from the parent?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370433/how-to-create-a-micro-frontend-bundle-with-webpack-that-shares-libraries-with-th) is quite similar. Does the answer help you out?

Comment: We do this with `externals` in the `webpack.config.js`.  If it's a shared lib we own, we also use a hash of the build in the name of the global the lib is exported to.  And we serve everything from CloudFront CDN, so there's good caching on the client side. So, we can continue to develop the shared libs we own and introduce breaking changes if needed, without too much overhead for the user. For stuff we don't own, we just get locked into major versions. Don't have an upgrade route yet, but will probably involve isolating older parts of the system and upgrading newer stuff.